# Joining variable to strings fails in PHP

Tags: php

I'm sorry that this is basic. When I use this PHP code it works fine:

```
$data = '{"reportID":1092480021}';
```

However, when I run my URL like this:

http://localhost:8000/new/reportget.php?type=1092480021

and use this PHP code:

```
$reportref = $_GET['type'];
$data = '{"reportID:".$reportref."}"';
```

I get the error

```
Error_description:reportID is required
```

I think it's an error with how I am joining my variable to the string but I can't understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: why did you put dots around `$reportref`?

Comment: $data = '{"reportID:"'.$reportref.'"}"';

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I thought that's how you join them together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is improperly quoted. To match the format in your first example use:

```
$data = '{"reportID":' . $reportref.'}';
```

Note there are no double quotes on the last curly.

Even better:

```
$reportref = 1092480021;
$data = [ 'reportId' => $reportref ];
var_dump(json_encode($data));
```

Output:

```
string(23) "{"reportId":1092480021}"
```

Answer (score 2):

For simple view and understanding, can you try out:

`$data = "{\"reportID\":$reportref}";`

Think that should sort it out

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
data = '{"reportID:"'.$reportref.'"}"';
```

Comment: This gives me {"reportID:"1092480021"}" which isn't quite right but I should be able to tweak it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It isn't working because you wrap all the value within single quote and when it come to concatenate the `$reprtref` you put directly `.$reportref` without closing the first single quote and after putting the value to concatenate you forget to open another single quote

```
'{"reportID:".$reportref."}"';
```

the correct value is

```
'{"reportID:"' . $reportref . '"}"';
```

and to match the way you specify your $data value It must be like this

```
'{"reportID":' . $reportref . '}';
```